# Matrix Optimization of $\max_{A} \mathrm{Trc} \left((I-A \cdot B) \cdot M \cdot (I-A \cdot B)^T + A KA^T \right)$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Suppose we have to positive definite matrices $M$ and $K$. 
I want to optimize the following expression 
\begin{align}
\max_{A} \mathrm{Trc} \left((I-A \cdot B) \cdot M \cdot (I-A \cdot B)^T + A KA^T \right)
\end{align}
where $I$ is the identity matrix and  $B$ some other matrix (assume we don't know much about $B$)

In the scalar the case the solution is given by
\begin{align}
a= \frac{bm}{b^2m+k}
\end{align}

Thank you for your help.

Comment: $A=\big(K+K^T+B(M+M^T)B^T\big)^{-1}(M+M^T)B^T$

Comment: @hans Could you please show me how you got it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the function in terms of the [Frobenius (:) Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) and find its differential
$$\eqalign{
 f &= (AB-I)M:(AB-I) + AK:A \cr\cr
df &= dA\,BM:(AB-I) +(AB-I)M:dA\,B + dA\,K:A + AK:dA \cr
   &= dA:(AB-I)M^TB^T +(AB-I)MB^T:dA + dA:AK^T + AK:dA \cr
   &= \Big((AB-I)M^TB^T +(AB-I)MB^T + AK^T + AK\Big):dA \cr\cr
}$$
Since $df=\Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}:dA\Big),\,$ the gradient must be
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial A} &= (AB-I)M^TB^T +(AB-I)MB^T + AK^T + AK \cr
  &= A(B(M^T+M)B^T + K^T + K) - (M+M^T)B^T \cr\cr
}$$
Setting the gradient equal to zero and solving for A yields
$$\eqalign{
 A(B(M+M^T)B^T + K^T + K) = (M+M^T)B^T \cr
 A = (B(M+M^T)B^T + K^T + K)^{-1} (M+M^T)B^T \cr
}$$

Comment: Do you have any good matrix calculus reference books?